# SQL Query Checking if Row's Date is Within X Amount of Days Of Previous Row

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I want to use SQL measure how effective a technician is at resolving an issue, by preventing another call-back to the equipment within 14 days. I would appreciate help on how to generate the last column of this table using a SQL query. (Assume dates are in format d/m/yyyy) (the descriptions in round brackets are only for your help in understanding the problem).

`Tech Last Name | Equipment Number | Notifications Date | Is Within 14 Days of Previous`
`Bob Anderson   | 10111231111      | 1/3/2021           | N`
`Bob Anderson   | 10111231111      | 28/2/2021          | Y (since the 28th of feb is within 14 days of first March)`
`Bob Anderson   | 10111231111      | 1/2/2021           | N`
`Bob Anderson   | 10000000001      | 28/1/2021          | N (since the equipment number is different from the previous)`

Example of Table Layout

[image]

The problem I have is generating the results of the last column [Is Within 14 Days of Previous], since this requires access to the data in the previous row which SQL was not designed to do. I am currently working on this problem in **Microsoft Access**, or there is also the option of using **VBA**. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here some possible solution.

Created on Access.
Demo table
[DemoTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s3dW.png)

Created a query as follows

```
SELECT d1.name
    ,d1.machine
    ,d1.maintenance_date 
    ,(d1.maintenance_date-(select max(d2.maintenance_date) 
            from demo d2 where d2.name = d1.name and d2.machine = d1.machine
            and d2.maintenance_date < d1.maintenance_date)) AS days_between
    FROM DEMO AS d1;
```

Results.

[QueryResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKRDp.png)